# Encrypted partition with user files not mounted at start up

Tags: password, encryption, startup

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 22.10 with two disks.
One is used for the system and home directories.
The other is used for "data", and it is encrypted.

The idea was to have some sensitive home folders (sym)linked to this "data" encrypted disk, for example `Documents`, `Downloads`, `Music`, `Videos`, etc.
I also configured this partition to be mounted at startup.

I logged in a couple of times and I realized that this disk was not mounted.
The symlinks were broken of course.

Then I realized that Ubuntu is asking me for a disk password *before* the login screen, but the password screen is shown for less than a second before it sends me to the login.
So when I log in the folder is not mounted or even accessible, which is confusing.

**Is this a bug? How can I make Ubuntu wait for me to type the disk password before sending me to the login screen.**
Even better, how can I make the encrypted disk to be mounted at login, just using the user password?

This is the configuration I used:

[image]